# Sailsjs: E_VALIDATION rule integer Value should be an integer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

**Sails version**: 0.12
**Node version**: 6.11.4
**NPM version**:  3.10.0
**DB adapter name**:  sails-mongo
**DB adapter version**: 0.12
**Operating system**: Linux

---

I have a problem with `integer` types. If I set it to `integer` then if the value is  null I receive the following error:

`{"error":"E_VALIDATION","status":400,"summary":"1 attribute is invalid","model":"Test","invalidAttributes":{"test":[{"rule":"integer","message":"Value should be an integer"}]}}`

My model configuration:

```
test: {
      type: 'integer'
 }
```

As I didn't set the `require` validator so `null` values should be accepted.

If I set the value with a integer or witha a string containing an integer then it work fine.

What I'm doing wrong here? Or how can I allow `null` values on integer fields?

Link to the issue on sailsjs: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4215

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed. The problem was that before the validation the value was NaN. Maybe this value was coming from the fronted input field or after the integer validation. Anyways it works fine by adding this check in the validation: 

`if (isNaN(attrs.test))
    attrs.test = null;`